# Tomcat integrated in Eclipse DB connection

Tags: java, database, eclipse, tomcat, jdbc

I'm finding a rather unusual problem. I have a web app that connects to my DB using the jdbc driver and creates the DB tables when the application is launched (hibernate hbm2ddl.auto=create). When I create a war and deploy it to tomcat from outside eclipse (simply copying the war to the webapps folder in tomcat) and launch the application, it creates the tables correctly. However, I integrated Tomcat with Eclipse(catalina_home set to the same tomcat installation as before, thus same config files).But this time, when I deploy the app from within eclipse, the tables are not created. I have tried a couple of things but nothing seems to work.
If you need more specific information please dont hessitate to ask.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I had the opposite problem, where things worked in Eclipse but not Tomcat by itself. You may need to be very explicit about the connection method to the database, that is what helped me. See my question and answer at [Tomcat JDBC connection works in Eclipse but not stand-alone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25130781/tomcat-jdbc-connection-works-in-eclipse-but-not-stand-alone/).

Comment: It was a duplicated dependency library in the tomcat/eclipse installation and the project...very difficult to find what it was, and very weird situation, but finally everything worked out.