# Exception when connecting to Sybase using JDBC Driver

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, sybase

I'm new to Sybase database and trying to connect to Sybase using Java JDBC connection and sajdbc4.jar, but getting an error:

> java.sql.SQLException: [Sybase][JDBC Driver][SQL Anywhere]Database server not found

Here is my connection string:

```
jdbc:sqlanywhere:uid=user;pwd=xxxx;eng=xx_sql;database=dummy;links=tcpip(host=xx.xx.xx.xx)
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly ensure that you point the database file to the SQL Anywhere Server and restart the server.

Secondly analyze your database logs, check if you can trace the connectivity with SQL PLUS or any other database connectivity tools.

If you are able to solve it, then that's fine or else I suspect that the issue to be related to this issue on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25130781/tomcat-jdbc-connection-works-in-eclipse-but-not-stand-alone)

As per this question, please make the following changes and I guess that the issue should be resolved

```
jdbc:sqlanywhere:Server=yourservername;uid=user;pwd=xxxx;port=2638;eng=xx_sql;database=dummy;links=tcpip(port=2638)
```

It is mandatory to mention the use of TCP/IP protocol to yourJDBC driver through the connection string above!

Hope this helps!